# scipy special beta function and integral

Tags: scipy, statistics

I have two values $a$ and $b$ where $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$ and I have to calculate the formula below.

...
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\text{abs}\left[( \frac{p_i^{(a - 1)} \times (1 - p_i)^{(b - 1)})}{\beta(a,b)} )- 1\right] dp_i

...

I have to calculate above value.
I am facing below error while doing that.
My equation is implemented as

...

```
import scipy.special as sc
import scipy.integrate as spi
integrand_np = lambda p_i:   abs(((p_i ** (a - 1)) * ((1 - p_i) ** (b - 1)) / (sc.beta(a,b)) - 1) / 2

result1, error = spi.quad(integrand_np, a, b)


<ipython-input-7-9c587cce0891>:35: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
underestimated.
result1, error = spi.quad(integrand_np, a, b)
```

...

Beta value is coming as zero. so the equation fails. If i try to use betaln function by changing equation as below, I am getting different values for small computations

I am getting an error. I tried to use betaln by changing my equation. Still I am facing below issue

> IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected,
> which prevents    the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The
> error may be    underestimated.

Sample a values = [1400, 440, 799]
Sample b values = [700,560, 1400]

To prevent error is there a way to use scipy.special.betaln.
I changed above formula as below to use betaln

$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 ( \frac{p_i^{(a - 1)} \times (1 - p_i)^{(b - 1)})}{\beta(a,b)} ) dp_i - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 1 dp_i

\frac{1}{2*beta(a,b)}\int_0^1 ( p_i^{(a - 1)} \times (1 - p_i)^{(b - 1)}) ) dp_i - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 1 dp_i

integralvalue = \int_0^1 ( p_i^{(a - 1)} \times (1 - p_i)^{(b - 1)}) ) dp_i
$$

Then I am applying log to use betaln function. But still it is not working.
...

```
import scipy.special as sc
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np

integrand = lambda p_i: abs(((p_i ** (p_count - 1)) * ((1 - p_i) ** (n_count - 1))))
   
integral_second_term = lambda p_i: 1/2
result1, error = spi.quad(integrand, a, b)



result2, error1 = spi.quad(integral_second_term, a, b)
final_log = np.log(result1) - sc.betaln(p_count, n_count) - np.log(2)
final_output = abs((np.exp(final_log)) - result2)
```

...

It is not giving correct values

I am getting an error saying roundoff error while integrating.

I tried log function also it is still not working